# Running Scrapy from bash (shell script)

Tags: java, bash, shell, scrapy

I have developed a web app in Java which uses Scrapy to get some data. To reach that, I invoke a shell script from Java:

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh myPath/myScript.sh");
 p.waitFor();
```

which contains

```
 #!/bin/bash

 cd mySpiderPath
 echo "We are going tu run scrapy"
 scrapy crawl mySpider
 echo "done!"
```

After running it, both "echo" are printed but scrapy does nothing. If I run myScript.sh from shell it works perfectly... I'm confused!

What can I do to try to debug this strange behavior?

**EDIT**

I have changed myScript.sh to run python version instead of scrapy command, and it doesn't work... so, the conclusion is that is not an "scrapy problem" but it is a bash script problem when it's invoked from Java...any ideas? (if I execute myScript.sh from shell it works fine)

```
 #!/bin/bash

 cd mySpiderPath
 echo "We are going tu run scrapy"
 python --version
 echo "done!"
```

Comment: Are you sure the scrapy command is defined in your process?  Maybe put the full path to the binary or make sure your PATH variable contains the path to that binary.  You can probably echo $PATH, I don't know scrapy, but can you try to do something else like scrapy -version or scrapy -help

Comment: I've changed 

    `scrapy crawl mySpider`

for 

    `scrapy version`

and still not working... it's like it doesn't recognize `scrapy` command, but any error is prompted. If I execute `scrapy version` from shell, it works fine

Comment: I have edited my question following your advices @Mike

Comment: I would add the echo $PATH in the script to see what your PATH variable looks like.  If scrapy directory (executed in python?) isn't in the PATH, you need to export the PATH variable to include the scrapy/python directory

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh myPath/myScript.sh");
```

to:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash myPath/myScript.sh");
```

This will probably run the script with `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh`, that often points to a simpler shell.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with no success... thanks anyway. I will try @Mike 's one